# Quiz app made using SQLite database ,runs on emulator but crashes on actual device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a student and first time studying android and trying to make a quiz app using       SQLite it works properly on emulator but crashes on android mobile

I am not able to understand the problem whenever I am trying to
install the quiz by copying its .apk it gets installed on android
phone but whenever I click on the button to show questions it crashes

This is my db helper class.

```
package com.example.quiz;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private final static String  DATABASE_NAME="questio.db";
        private final static int  DATABASE_VERSION=2;
        private final static String  Android="quiz1";

        private final static String  php="quiz2";

        private final static String  ID="id";
        private final static String  score="score";


        private final static String  Question="question";
        private final static String  answer="ans";
        private final static String  op1="opa";
        private final static String  op2="opb";
        private final static String  op3="opc";

        public static final String SQL_Create="create table " +Android+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Question+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+answer+" TEXT,"+op1+" TEXT, "+op2+" TEXT, "+op3+" TEXT"+")";
        public static final String SQL_Create2="create table " +php+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Question+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+answer+" TEXT,"+op1+" TEXT, "+op2+" TEXT, "+op3+" TEXT"+")";







        SQLiteDatabase db1;
        public dbhelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(SQL_Create);
            db.execSQL(SQL_Create2);

            db1=db;
            db.close();


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

All statements of onUpgrade method are commented so that the
questions inserted in the table is not lost.

```
@Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {





        //db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+Android);

            //db.execSQL("drop table "+php);


            //db.execSQL("drop table if exist"+TableName);
            //onCreate(db);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stubS

        }
        public void insertIntoTable(String str1,String str2,String str3,String str5,String str4)
        {
             db1=getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(Question, str1);
            values.put(answer, str2);
            values.put(op1, str3);
            values.put(op2, str5);
            values.put(op3, str4);
            db1.insert(Android, null, values);

        }
        public void insertIntoTable2(String str1,String str2,String str3,String str4,String str5)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(Question, str1);
            values.put(answer, str2);
            values.put(op1, str3);
            values.put(op2, str5);
            values.put(op3, str4);
            db1.insert(php, null, values);

        }




        public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
            List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +Android;
        //String del="delete from "+Android+ " where ID=16";
            SQLiteDatabase db2=this.getReadableDatabase();
            //db2.execSQL(del);
        Log.d("chk", selectQuery);
            Cursor cursor = db2.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Question quest = new Question();
                    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                    quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                    Log.d("quest", quest.getQUESTION());
                    quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                    quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                    quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(5));
                    quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(4));
                    quesList.add(quest);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // return quest list
            return quesList;
        }

        public int rowcount()
        {
            int row=0;
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Android;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            row=cursor.getCount();
            return row;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Could you please post the crashlog from adb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Question title is bad....

Comment: The logcat shows no error

Comment: @sakshi if its crashing, then there must be the error dear.

Answer (score 1):

For any crash, see the logcat for helpful information to locate the problem. Always include the stacktrace in your questions, too. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for more.

In the code, don't call `close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase` that was passed to your helper's `onCreate()`.

Why it "works" on emulator is possible because if the database file already exists (set up with an earlier version of your code), the `onCreate()` callback is not invoked. It's only called when the database file was just created. You'll see a crash if you e.g. uninstall your app on the emulator or clear its data. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) for more.